# Windows Form application with multiple background Tasks?

Tags: winforms, service, task

My question is the following:
I have a winform application which does some text file processes in the background and I show the process status on a winform form.
There could be 3 background processess maximum (depends on the user settings).
Each background process should check a folder and as soon as there is a text file in there, one of them should pick it up.
When it finishes with the file process it should start to look for the files again.
Also, have some settings in a .ini file which can be changed through the winform as well.

This all works fine.

However, I am very new with Task, Threads and background processes.

I managed to do this which quite works, but i am sure that this is not the best solution.

```
public void MainTask()
        {
            mainTask1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Task1Process());
            mainTask2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Task2Process());
        }
   
public async void Task1Process()
        {           
            task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                DoSomething();
            });
            task1.Wait();
            if (task1.IsCompleted && !isSettings)
            {
                Task1Process();
            }
        } 
  
public async void Task2Process()
        {
            task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                DoSomething();
            });
            task2.Wait();
            if (task2.IsCompleted && !isSettings)
            {
                Task2Process();
            }
        }
```

If I use the task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() with the task1.Wait() , then the winform is unusable until the process finishes.
That is why i started a MainTask and triggered the other tasks from there. In this way the winform is usable.
Also an issue is that the Thread.Sleep only works on start and then it does not wait at all.

Again my question is what would be the best approach to do this?

Note that the application should run 24/7 and start on windows automaticcaly without any user logged in.

I did research that a Windows Service should solve the issue, but that looks even more difficult for me at the moment.

Note:
I managed to create a windows service but could not manage to run it on windows start.
Also, could not manage to set a method to process some local files. The service started though.
I used Timer (instead of Thread) and it did write to a log file every second, but could not manage to trigger a text file process method.
Also, I need to figure out how to connect Winform (or browser gui maybe as it only runs on localhost anyway)  with the service.

Please let me know your thoughts and maybe some useful links where I could learn some more.

Any help would be approtiated.

Thanks